# I want to open the csv if file already created in that location with same file name otherwise create on new csv to record my scrape data in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to open the CSV if a file is already created in that location with the same file name otherwise create on new CSV to record my scrape data with headings but If the file has already been created it should record only data not repeat headings again on the same CSV file in python code to scrape and save data from multiple articles and save in one CSV.

```
# =============== Data Store +++++++++++++++++++++
Data = [[Category,Headlines,Author,Source,Published_Date,Feature_Image,Content,url]]
try:
    df = pd.DataFrame (Data, columns = ['Category','Headlines','Author','Source','Published_Date','Feature_Image','Content','URL'])
    print(df)
    with open('C:/Users/Public/pagedata.csv', 'a') as f:
        df.to_csv(f, header=False)
except:
    df = pd.DataFrame (Data, columns = ['Category','Headlines','Author','Source','Published_Date','Feature_Image','Content','URL'])
    print(df)
    df.to_csv('C:/Users/Public/pagedata.csv', header=True)
```

Comment: Move all of your code into the code block in the question body and make sure it looks correct on the web page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide code to two sections in try/except. First you try to check if file with db exists - if yes, in the same moment you can concatenate new data to old data.
If not, you are just creating new data(headers are True on default).

```
cols = ['Category','Headlines','Author','Source','Published_Date','Feature_Image','Content','URL']
try:
    opened_df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Public/pagedata.csv')
    opened_df = pd.concat([opened_df,pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = cols)])
except:
    opened_df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = cols)

opened_df.to_csv('C:/Users/Public/pagedata.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: This is working fine for me but now it's making more columns for each time new data is saved in the excel sheet.

Comment: Like index columns? Please modify last sentence in df.to_csv. Add : index=False